# Object Library not registered

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access-2007, sharepoint-2007, excel-2007

I am using Access(2007) vba to process an Excel(ACCDB) workbook on a Sharepoint 2007 document library. In the process, I update two properties using the ExcelWB.ContentTypeProperties() proerty. It's been working fine literally for years. Today, it stopped working. It throws a "Object Library not registered" error. Research seems to suggest I've somehow gotten an old DLL for Excel registered, and the interface is using an old DLL that doesn't support the property.

My libraries are all found, no changes were made (by me...) in the last month to the machine. It's a client machine, so I can't speak for MS updates, etc. that were made. How can I fix this? It's literally got my client sitting on her hands, unable to work.

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWB As Excel.WorkBook
Dim xlSH As Excel.Worksheet
Dim xlRA As Excel.Range
Dim bValidWorkbook As Boolean
Dim lngTrueHighestRow As Long
Dim strWorkbookName As String

WorkbookMessage , 3                                   'Clears the message queue
bValidWorkbook = True
strNewTimesheetStatus = "Rejected"
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
xlApp.visible = False                   'Don't let the workbook be shown
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(URL)    'Open the workbook

lngCurrentVendorID = ParseVendor(strCurrentVendorName)         'Sets up the vendor recordset and the Labor rate Recordset. If it returns 0, it couldn't find the vendor
If lngCurrentVendorID = 0 Then
    bValidWorkbook = False
    WorkbookMessage "Workbook Rejected -- Vendor could not be validated"
    GoTo ExitWorkbook
End If
'
'   If the workbook is read-only, we can't proceed
'
If xlWB.ReadOnly Then
    bValidWorkbook = False
    WorkbookMessage "Workbook Rejected -- Workbook is read-only state"
    GoTo ExitWorkbook
End If

Set xlSH = xlWB.Worksheets(1)           'Must be the first worksheet in the workbook
strWorkbookName = xlWB.NAME

Set xlRA = xlSH.UsedRange               'xlRA is the range of cells in the first workbook that are "USED"
strSheetArray = xlRA                    'This sets an array of variants to the two dimensional range xlRA
xlRA.EntireRow.Hidden = False           'Unhides all rows to prevent misunderstandings.
```

...
...
...
...

```
If Not xlWB.ReadOnly Then
    xlWB.ContentTypeProperties("TimesheetStatus") = strValidateWorkbook***
    xlWB.ContentTypeProperties("OverrideStatus") = strNewOverrideStatus
    xlWB.Save 
End If
```

Comment: Could you post the specific lines of code where the error occurs?  Also, what happens if you change the declaration of ExcelWb to `Set ExcelWb = CreateObject("Excel.WorkBook")`  Late binding may resolve versioning issues, although you may lose a bit in performance if it's being called a lot.

Comment: If Not xlWB.ReadOnly Then
        xlWB.ContentTypeProperties("TimesheetStatus") = strValidateWorkbook
        xlWB.ContentTypeProperties("OverrideStatus") = strNewOverrideStatus
        xlWB.Save
        
    End If

Comment: This code worked perfectly for literally a year or two. suddenly broke. I did install Lync 2010 today....

Comment: Jimmy, I'll try that. In the meantime, I've bludgeoned it to death with a huge sledge and gotten it to work. I collected an array of the items I processed, closed all the recordsets, etc. detached and reattached the table representing the items in the library, then updated the appropriate rows using currentdb.execute "Update....set...." It worked, but is some poor programming practice....